# how to do ng-transclude with ui router's component API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm running AngularJS with UI Router. When I hit a certain route, I want to render a component.

I also want to be able to pass a child component into the component via  ngTransclude.

If I were to do this in a template, I would do something like:

But now, UI router recommends i use the [`component` api].[1](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component)

Does anyone know if it's possible to define ngTransclude options with ui router's component API? or do I have to do the old way, using template?

Here is what I have now:

```
.state('builder.items.selectedItem', {
      views: {
        'myViews@builder': {
          component: 'first-component', //this is the new API
        },
      },
      resolve: {
        item: /*@ngInject*/ function(dataService) {
          return dataService.getItems()[0];
        },
      },
```

where my component definition is

```
const component = {
  ngTransclude: true,
  bindings: {
    item: '<',
  },
  controller: Blahblah,
  template: `<div>
    Hello i am inside first component and my item is {{item}}
    <ng-transclude>
    </ng-transclude>
  </div`
}
```

Comment: there is a way... but your better off just specifying a template or an html file with your component and transclude that way. But if you are bent on using component you could specify a binding: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#bindings  the binding to specify is the ngTransclude directive which you will specify in a a string the html you'd like to transclude, there might be a better way  but this is what I gathered from ui routers docs and ngTransclude docs

Comment: @floor hey thanks a lot! i ended up specifying it as a component, and refactoring so i didn't need to do ngTransclude.